# querying hbase in java if value of some fields are known

Tags: java, mysql, apache, hadoop, hbase

I am using org.apache.hadoop.hbase library to query hbase.
In h-base I have following:

table name : Employees
in this table I have following fields:
emp_id,name, age, designation, joining_date

how can I find designation of employee if I have his joining_date and name only.
I am using something like:

```
public static void getOneRecord (Configuration conf, String tableName, String rowKey, String rowKey2) throws IOException{
        HTable table = new HTable(conf, tableName);
        Get get = new Get(rowKey.getBytes());
        Result rs = table.get(get);
        for(KeyValue kv : rs.raw()){
            System.out.print(new String(kv.getRow()) + " " );
            System.out.print(new String(kv.getFamily()) + ":" );
            System.out.print(new String(kv.getQualifier()) + " " );
            System.out.print(kv.getTimestamp() + " " );
            System.out.println(new String(kv.getValue()));
        }
    }
```

how can I extend it to 2 row keys.

Note: It is guaranteed that only one value will be returned by this pair query.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get a record based on the columns which are not row keys. Please confirm this. If yes, following are the options

1. Good row key design for performance. If you would be querying more based on a column other than row key, you can consider looking at modifying row key design to append that column as part of row key. Then you can use get or scan with row key range, row filter or [FuzzyRowFilter](http://blog.sematext.com/2012/08/09/consider-using-fuzzyrowfilter-when-in-need-for-secondary-indexes-in-hbase/)
2. Secondary index is one option.
3. Use filters(in your case two SingleColumnValueFilter) and add them as part of scan.[here](http://www.hadooptpoint.com/filters-in-hbase-shell/)